# Rate of change of sphere

Tags: derivatives

The radius $r$ of a sphere of volume $V$ is given by $r= (3V/4π)^{1/3}$

A student calculates the following:

$$[r(1)-r(0.5)]/0.5$$

$$[r(1.5)-r(1)]/0.5$$

$$[r(2)-r(1.5)]/0.5$$

What can be said about the pattern of the results?

Should I change the first formula so that it becomes $V=(4/3)πr^3$ first?

Comment: I would start by performing the calculation indicated.  Presumably the argument of $r$ is the volume that you should calculate $r$ at.  The three numbers you get are approximations to the derivative of $r$ with respect to $V$ (times a constant).

Comment: I have already tried that but the pattern turned out to be r; r; r; ...I don't what to make of that

Comment: With the edit, you are computing approximations to the derivative with $h=\frac 12$.  $r(0.5)$ is the value of $r$ you get when $V=0.5$.  It should be a number.

Comment: If you are getting $r,r,r,\dots$, then you're doing something wrong. Maybe you are interpreting $r(1)$ to mean "$r$ times 1", when it actually means "$r$ of 1", that is, the function $r$ evaluated at $V=1$.

Comment: Make any progress, John?

Comment: Are you still here, John?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.